# why does included jquery always cause problems

Tags: jquery

I am taking an html template that is fully functioning with the jquery and javascript in the footer and I am converting it into WordPress. I have done this a few times and I always have trouble with the jquery. I always want to deregister the included jquery and use my own scripts that are up and running on my template. I feel like I am doing something wrong here because I have read that WordPress has jquery enabled by default; yet, when I add my scripts, the site crashes. so If I take this out of my footer

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and replace it with a call from function.php like so

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
```

it crashes.

The last snippet puts the jquery in the header. I found an option to add it to the footer on this site but it didn't work. is there a "Propper" way?

Comment: Are you including it in an action hook or just directly calling wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: I am including it in the twentyfourteen_scripts which is being called on the wp_enqueue_scripts. So the add_action.

Comment: could be because when you enqueue jQuery with `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');`, it loads jQuery files from wp-includes folder which runs in noconflict mode. But your custom jQuery rules are written for normal jQuery.

Comment: My first thought is you are loading two jQuery libraries. You may need to de-register the included jquery, and re-enqueue it in the way you want. Here is an example that uses CDN instead, but you can get the gist: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/. Also, you can pass a parameter to load it in the footer: `wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );`.

Comment: I read an article by someone who claimed to be an admin here. he posted that deregistering jquery and using your own is a very bad idea. In his words, if you do that, you don't deserve to call youself a web developer. I am trying to use jquery included with WordPress. i just can't help but notice that everything always crashes when you use bundled jquery. I have not had one theme that worked wihtout massive amounts of hacking.

Comment: @Jamie jQuery in WordPress runs in noconflict mode. And moving all your code to noconflict jQuery is not that hard, just need to add jQuery wrapper around it.